# Heroku - ActionView::Template::Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, audiojs

I adding in my rails app "audiojs" music player (http://kolber.github.com/audiojs/)

on localhost all good and work, but heroku says:

```
"We're sorry, but something went wrong."
```

log

```
ActionView::Template::Error (audiojs/audio.min.js isn't precompiled)
```

how to solve the problem?

Comment: Could be that your assets failed to precompile properly. Have a look through your logs and this help doc: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3x-asset-pipeline-cedar

Comment: New error

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/undefinedplayer-graphics.gif"):

Comment: last logs http://old.pastie.org/6459850

help me pls!

Comment: looks like you've got a javascript variable that's returning undefined. How are you prefixing the asset path?

Comment: @Gavin Miller 
I laid out all the sources on github. This version works fine on the localhost . Please help me identify and solve the problem! 
https://github.com/BDAinc/chernobylmusic.net

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your main page javascript. You're trying to load a track, but the elements you're looking for don't exist so you're getting the undefined error.

```
var audio = a[0];
first = $('ol a').attr('data-src');

// Add this code to layouts/application.html.erb
// First is coming back undefined on your root route.
if (first == undefined)
  console.log("First is undefined! Will cause error in audio track");

$('ol li').first().addClass('playing');
audio.load(first);
```

Whereas, you're setting `data-src="<%= show.preview %>"` in `releases/show.html.erb` (and `index.html.erb`) and the code works without issue there.

Your options are to detect if there are no order list items and not try to automatically play an audio track, or add audio tracks to your main page.

Comment: Oh mate. i stupid. just needed to adding:
    gem "audiojs".
then in application.js adding //= require audiojs and no problem.

thx for you time and support!

love!